# Search dataframe by multiple column values

Tags: python, dataframe

This is my dataframe:

|  | PERSON | SUBJECT | SCORE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | Math | 7 |
| 1 | A | English | 8 |
| 2 | A | Math | 3 |
| 3 | B | English | 9 |
| 4 | B | Art | 3 |
| 5 | C | Math | 3 |
| 6 | C | Art | 3 |
| 7 | C | Chemistry | 7 |

How to get student name if his Math score is 7 and English score is 8 (in this case that is student A)?

i've tried like this:

```
    data = {'PERSON': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
                'SUBJECT': ['Math', 'English', 'Math', 'English', 'Art', 'Math', 'Art', 'Chemistry'],
                'SCORE' : [7, 8, 3, 9, 3, 3, 3, 7]
                }
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['PERSON', 'SUBJECT', 'SCORE'])
    
st = df.loc[(df['SUBJECT'] == 'Math') & (df['SCORE'] == 7)]
```

This gives me

> 0        A    Math      7

How to get only person which has subjects Math with score 7 and English with score 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with:

```
df.set_index('PERSON', inplace=True)

st = df.loc[(df['SUBJECT'] == 'Math') & (df['SCORE'] == 7)]
st2 = df.loc[(df['SUBJECT'] == 'English') & (df['SCORE'] == 8)]

index1 = st.index
index2 = st2.index

if index1==index2:
    print(index1)
else:
    print("None")
```